# Why does my java guessing game not work after the first loop

Tags: java, substring, indexof, string-length

I'm working on this guessing game where the user needs to guess the word in under 6 tries. They have the ability to try and guess the whole word but if guessed incorrectly the game ends. When the game ends it gives them the option to play again. My problem is that when I try to guess the word for the second time it gives me an error only when I enter `n` character.

I'm later going to replace add an array instead of the static BRAIN word and randomize it but I want to figure this out.

Here is the code:

```
/*
* WordGuess.java

*/
import java.util.Scanner;

/**        
* Plays a word guessing game with one player.
* */

public class WordGuess {

//Main meathod    
public static void main(String[] arqs) {

final String SECRET_WORD = "BRAIN";
final String FLAG = "!";
String wordSoFar = "", updatedWord = "";
String letterGuess, wordGuess = "";
int numGuesses = 0;
String repeat = "";

Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

/* begin game */
System. out. println ( "World Guess game. \n" );

do{
numGuesses = 0;
wordSoFar = "";
updatedWord = "";

for (int i = 0; i < SECRET_WORD.length() ; i++) {
wordSoFar += "-"; //word, as dashes
}
 System.out.println("Your word is  ");
System.out.println(wordSoFar + "\n"); //displays dashes
/* a11ow player to make guesses */

do{
System.out.print("Enter a letter (" + FLAG + " to guess entire world): ");
letterGuess = input.nextLine();
letterGuess = letterGuess.toUpperCase() ;
/* increment number of guesses */
//numGuesses += 1;
/* player correctly guessed a letter--excract string in wordSoFar
* up to the letter guessed and then append guessed. letter to that
* string Next, extract rest of wordSoFar and append after the guessed
* letter
*/

if (SECRET_WORD.indexOf(letterGuess) >= 0) {
updatedWord = wordSoFar.substring(0, SECRET_WORD.indexOf(letterGuess));
updatedWord += letterGuess;
updatedWord += wordSoFar.substring(SECRET_WORD.indexOf(letterGuess)+1,
wordSoFar. length() ) ;
wordSoFar = updatedWord;
}else {
    numGuesses += 1;
}
/* display guessed letter instead of dash */
System.out.println(wordSoFar + "\n");
} while (!letterGuess.equals(FLAG) && !wordSoFar.equals(SECRET_WORD) && numGuesses < 6);

/* finish game anil display message anil number of guesses */
if (letterGuess.equals(FLAG)) {
System.out.println("What is your guess? ");
wordGuess = input.nextLine() ;
wordGuess = wordGuess.toUpperCase() ;
}
if (wordGuess.equals(SECRET_WORD) || wordSoFar.equals(SECRET_WORD)) {
System.out.println ( "You won! " ) ;
} else {
System.out.println("Sorry. You 1ose.");
}
System.out.println("The secret word is " + SECRET_WORD);
System.out.println("You made " + numGuesses + " mistake.");

    System.out.println("Would you like to play again?");
    repeat = input.next();

}while(repeat.equalsIgnoreCase("Y"));

System.out.println("GOOD BYE THANKS FOR PLAYING!");
}

}//end of Word Guess class
```

Comment: What error message do you get?

Comment: Can you format the code so that it's more readable? (Indentations)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Solution 1** - You can move `Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);` to the **first** `do`
>   block

```
  do {

        //Has moved to the first do block
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);          

        //Rest of your code

      }
```

> **Solution 2** - You can use `input.next()` insted of `input.nextLine()` in the **second** `do` block

```
do {

    System.out.print("Enter a letter (" + FLAG + " to guess entire world): ");

    // input.nextLine() Has changed to input.next()
    letterGuess = input.next();

    //.. Rest of code

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Y` input for playing again is being read in as the first character of the word. You read in the full line of input

```
System.out.print("Enter a letter (" + FLAG + " to guess entire world): ");
letterGuess = input.nextLine();   // <---------- HERE
letterGuess = letterGuess.toUpperCase() ;
```

but when you ask if they want to play again you only do `input.next()`, meaning that there is still some input in the buffer when this code gets called.

---

If you replace `input.next()` with `input.nextLine()` like so

```
System.out.println("You made " + numGuesses + " mistake.");
System.out.println("Would you like to play again?");
repeat = input.next(); // <---------- CHANGE this to repeat = input.nextLine();
```

then your program works as expected.

Comment: @ARYA8B No worries! If my answer solved your problem, don't forget to accept it by clicking the checkmark to the left :)